# Is it ok to ask I-don't-care-about-your-language type questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Let me explain. Many times when I'm forced to venture outside of my territory, my conversations (not always on Stack Overflow) tend to go a little something like this:

> **Me**: I just need the contents in `~/path/to/my/ZipFile.zip/zipfolder` to be placed in some directory programagically so I can get on with my life. How do I unzip files from a nested folder in `bash`?
>
> **The Masters**: Have you tried using `Man`?
>
> **Me**: Man...? There's a man involved? Who is this *man*, and why does he hold the secrets to `bash` scripting?
>
> **The Masters**: jfgi
>
> **Me**: Oh, I get it! It must be some new lingo the kids are using. Google = *The Man*. I read you loud and clear. *wink
>
> **The Masters**: No, you idiot, I mean...ugh....look, just type this in your terminal: `man unzip -t -i` (I still don't know bash).
>
> **Me**: Yeah, that reminds me....Out of curiosity, what's the deal with those "dash thingies"? Is there a list, or something?
>
> **The Masters**: You don't even know the "dash thingies"??? It's obvious that you need to fully learn the language before asking for help in this case. [I found this book on Amazon to be very helpful](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-KuRTv5NyJq4/T3Ehaar950I/AAAAAAAAAlg/l4m11Pg8e0I/s1600/understanding%2Bwomen%2Byea.jpg)! It'll get you where you're going.
>
> **The Book**:
>
> > Chapter 1: Introduction--The `hello world` program.
> >
> > > *Writing computer code is sort of like designing a clock. All the pieces must work together and--* zzzZZZzzz...
>
> **Me**: Listen, I appreciate the help. Really, I do. But I never intended, or feel there's a need to, go this deep. I just need this quick solution that smells like a one-liner--two tops. Any help?
>
> **The Masters**: You'll never be a good programmer if you're only going to half-ass things. A novice needs to grow. There's no shame in it.
>
> **Me**: I'm not trying to do homework, or anything. I really just need this quick solution...
>
> **The Masters**: Such a shame. Some people just don't know how to help themselves. Sad, really...

Eventually I'm able to convince/pursuade/trick them into what I need. But I have to ask: What's wrong with this? My question in no way was meant to belittle your language, or disrespect the tireless hours and work you put into becoming proficient in it. Yes, it's **always** a good idea to learn new things, and I very well *could* take the time to learn the entire language; but with so many experts gathered in one place on the internet, is that really the *best* way to solve this once-and-done problem of mine? Not saying `bash` is a bad language. Learning `bash` could very well be beneficial to me tomorrow? Maybe. Today, hell no.

If your convictions prevent you from answering outright, you'd be surprised how helpful an answer like this can be:

> It sounds like you want to unzip everything, move what you need to where you need it, and delete the rest. Try looking into the `mv` and `rm` commands.

Now, Stack Overflow is a special breed. Not every question like this is welcome on the main site; but what about the chat? Only those with high enough reputation are even allowed to chat, which diminishes the trolls, and goodfornothings, etc.

In terms of asking protocol, are these questions ok (so long as they're asked clearly without duplicates)?

---

### Edit

The more this conversation goes on, the more apparent it becomes to me that emotion is playing a much bigger role here than it needs to. [Yes, it just so happens that this is a real question i asked](https://superuser.com/q/720700/302646). But its use here is due to its *convenience* as way to illustrate *other* experiences i've had. Why would one feel the need to drudge through my questions history over this, or remind me of the importance of "being polite"? It's as if many of you are coming into this discussion having already decided that i'm am an asshole. I see no rudeness here. Perhaps the title is distracting, or maybe i'm not as funny as i think i am, or maybe you guys are more robotic than i thought you were. Nevertheless, if we cut out the Abbott & Costello, remove the "jerk-colored goggles", and examine this conversation from a higher level, it's easier to see the asker's point of view:

> **Me**: I have a small problem that requires the help of someone with a primary level of proficiency in a discipline that is completely unknown to me. Could any of you who have mastered the discipline spare the few seconds to help me avoid wasting weeks?
>
> **The Masters**: Have you tried using this esoteric tool commonly utilized by `bash` programmers?
>
> **Me**: I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. Is this the solution to my problem?
>
> **The Masters**: I refuse to answer that question.
>
> **Me**: Using inductive reasoning on the little amount of information given, i have incorrectly come to an understanding that is miles away from where the conversation actually is.
>
> **The Masters**: Perhaps it would be best to give you the function call to the esoteric tool previously mentioned.
>
> **Me**: I don't think this function call is the solution to my problem, but it's something. Perhaps it just needs *fine-tuned* to my specific example, in the form of these "dash thingies". Is there a global list of "dash thingies" i could reference and play with?
>
> **The Masters**: People who know what those "dash thingies" are know `bash`. People who know `bash` know how to solve your problem. Therefore, it must be the case that you must learn `bash` in order to solve your problem. Here is an effective way to learn `bash`.
>
> **Me**: Learning `bash` is exactly what i was trying to avoid, as i'm not convinced it's necessary at this juncture given the fact that my need for `bash` begins & ends with this small task. Not to be rude AT ALL, but i already know the value of education & hard work, and much time has been wasted trying to avoid giving me a more direct answer. Is there anyone willing to help me out in this regard?
>
> **The Masters**: If you are not willing to learn `bash` as we have, it must be the case that you are trying to get us do your work for you, which both disrespects us and the effort we've put in getting to the level we are at.

As you can see, this question is more about misunderstandings and divergent expectations. This is why i've accepted @jmort253's answer, who reminds us that any question can be answered, so long as it is framed as clearly and specifically as possible--**to the benefit of both sides**.

Comment: You could ask your question on Super User where it probably is a better fit than SO in the first place. And if you formulate it well, you get an answer without all the drama you describe ... [oh wait](http://superuser.com/questions/720700/how-do-i-unzip-files-from-a-nested-folder), so ... 1. what is this post based on? 2. At the very least display an attitude where you're willing to learn.

Comment: To be fair, I'm not seeing anything that suggests the OP does not want to learn. There is being hesitant to learn, and then there is being hesitant to waste time. If all you want to know is how to work on a command line, spending a few days with an entire book on shell scripting isn't the most efficient way to go about it.

Comment: Yeh, and building on what @BoltClock says, it's a balance. Showing you've at least tried it yourself can go a long way to breaking the ice with people and hopefully not having them hit you over the head with the manual. :) Stack Overflow is definitely here so we don't have to read War and Peace sized documentation.

Comment: "solve this once-and-done problem" implies laziness and not a desire to learn.

Comment: Don't read too much into it, @Bart. It just made for a convenient example.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: As the old saying goes, *There's a time for everything*. There's a time to learn, and a time to solve problems.

Comment: But you're not solving problems.  You're asking others to solve your problem.  At least feign the desire to learn.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: No! At the very least, i'm asking for a "road sign". There's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: Yes there is.  SO is for well-formed questions with real answers.  Not "road signs."

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: "*It sounds like you want to unzip everything...*" **is** a real answer. It may not be as concrete as you'd like, but it is objective and direct. Any user facing the same problem in the future would benefit just as much from reading it.

Comment: How do I look into `mv` and `rm` commands? Does it mean anything they both contain an `m`? Can I replace them with a `z`, for `zip`?

Comment: If you already think your solution is going to be `just a 1 liner`, then you really shouldn't be asking the question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: If you were going to do a lot in bash it is worth learning how to use the documentation... You could then answer your subsequent questions yourself a lot quicker and spare yourself all the hassle.

Comment: A lot of you seem to be displaying exactly the attitude that the OP is frustrated with... I'm a Java programmer primarily, I've also never owned or done much work with `nix` systems so I know next to nothing about them. But once in a blue moon I have to go onto one and mess around for a few minutes. I don't *need* to know the ins and outs of bash for what I do, but occasionally I might need to look up how to do something. Reading the entire bash user manual takes time that I don't have - I already have a lot of other things that I need to be reading around on, such as Java 8.

Comment: Your probably-intended-to-be-goofy replies come off as snide. If someone's not really helping you the way you need, don't waste more of both of your valuable time by giving them grief or trying to expand your query ("what's the deal with the dashes"). Just find someone else who will help you.

Comment: There is an expectation that you will HAVE SOME CLUE as to what you are doing and BE WILLING TO INVEST TIME to understand the answers you are given instead of saying the equivalent of "GIVE ME THE CODEZ".  If someone gives you the exact command line snippet you need, you will copy paste it, then be back in 15 minutes with another request that could be solved in 5 minutes of Googling. To you this may be "Come on! This is like 5 minutes of work for you where it would be 20 for me!" but consider that every hour, hundreds of these "It's just a quick one!" questions get asked.

Comment: @Blackhawk: The reasoning in your comment echoes much of what is in the accepted answer; but this idea of "have some clue as to what you are doing" goes against the whole point of asking the "I-don't-care-about-your-language" question! It's not that one needs to "know what they're doing" in this case, they just need to "have some clue as to what they **need**", which is why I've accepted jmort253's answer. If the master takes offense and demands tribute in the form of independent learning of their language, that's their prerogative.

Comment: @NoobSaibot I'm not particularly offended by "I-don't-care-about-your-language" questions, it's more frustration. That type of question ends up being a mythical Hydra - answer one and five more pop up in its place, possibly from users that ask such questions serially. The frustration isn't at the individual question or user, rather it's at the whole category of question/attitude which tends to chew up a lot of tedious time but then has answers that are useful to only a handful of people in the long run. (Also, sorry for my CAPS, upon reflection they were not very constructive :( )

Comment: Hmm...Not sure if we're now down-voting because this question *shouldn't have been asked*, or if we're down-voting just because we *don't like* the question that was asked...

Comment: would you prefer Stack Overflow to be more like a [Mechanical Turk](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232114/165773)?

Comment: Or downvoting to help jmort253 gets a [reversal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal) badge...

Comment: Your own dialog belies your "I-don't-care-about-your-language" point: "Yeah, that reminds me....Out of curiosity, what's the deal with those "dash thingies"? Is there a list, or something?" That _vastly_ expands the scope of what you're asking beyond "I really just need this quick solution".

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Are you still looking at the first version of the conversation? The second version should be clearer, as i used more "robotic" phrasing. The asker recognizes that the "dash-thingies" are important in `bash`, but rather than taking the college course, asks for "the list" of "dash-thinggies" he can use to find his quick solution.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: To better explain the context, this whole exchange all comes down to [fish](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/m/maimonides326751.html). The Masters want to teach the asker how to fish; while the asker (having already learned that skill), for this situation, really just needs a single fish. What's so bad about that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Keep in mind that there's multiple parties involved in these transactions, all with their own feelings, dreams, drama, and *limited time and energy*. In other words, it's not just your time that's on the line.

In this particular example, I think you could minimize a lot of the hostility by explaining more about the *why* of what you're trying to do. When details are missing in a question, it may feel like it's saving you time, but in reality it makes any potential answerer have to make assumptions about why you're trying to do what you're trying to do, which actually comes back around full circle to take up more of your time and increase the likelihood of lower quality answers that don't help you.

For instance, they may misunderstand what you're trying to do. If that happens, those folks may spend their valuable time providing you a solution, only for you to come back and exclaim:

> no !! thta is not what im trying to do it doesnt work!!

Not only does that waste your time, but it also wastes the answerers time, and that's not good for anyone.

Now, with that said, the person in your example is perhaps a little bit too easily angered and should really go sit in a quiet space for some time and contemplate his or her existence, but the fact that you had to come back with a follow up question suggests that you didn't include enough detail to make your problem clear. Had it been more clear, this person either would have been able to give you the answers you seek and then quietly move on to go do something constructive, like kicking their dog, or just skip your post altogether and wait for someone else to help you.

Keep in mind that, as an asker, what you contribute is *extremely valuable*, assuming it includes enough detail. Good questions have keywords in them that help others with the same problem find those posts, and without good questions, we don't have good answers. So don't feel like it's a waste of time to put effort into writing clear questions. There are folks out there who will benefit because of the legacy you leave behind. Hope this helps.

Also, I want to add that, in real life conversations, there is a productivity element to bugging your coworkers about problems that you have. Asking them things you could look up or find on your own pulls them out of the zone, as described in Joel's blog post, [Where do These People Get Their (Unoriginal) Ideas?](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000068.html). Joel claims that it's not easy to get in the zone, and I concur:

> If you take a 1 minute interruption by a coworker asking you a question, and this knocks out your concentration enough that it takes you half an hour to get productive again, your overall productivity is in serious trouble.

Comment: That does not appear to be an accurate representation of the OP's writing style.

Comment: It depends on whether the follow-up question ties in with the original question in the first place. For example, in this case, it's clear the follow-up question arose based on the answer that was given - the OP couldn't have had this question without prior knowledge of the language (which prompted them to ask the original question in the first place). I know you're not suggesting that a follow-up question *necessarily* has to tie in with the original, I'm just giving an example of when that might not be the case.

Comment: Sounds like there could be a lack of research then in that case, @BoltClock, which is perhaps why some of the detail is missing. I think this is why we ask people to show their research, not because we're afraid someone might get something for free or without sweating for it but because there's an actual cost incurred by the people trying to help.

Comment: True, in this case since the OP knows that they can use something called bash, they have just enough information they need to be able to research their problem.

Comment: Also, in this case, it feels like the follow up question was in response to an answer that was given because the question wasn't clear. It's kind of like a waterfall effect where things keep going south from there. What's more, even if the asker were to clarify the question at this point, the answerers who already participated now have preconceived notions about the asker and the problem, and those are issues they'll have to overcome. Sometimes it feels like being in a car with someone who says "go left", and the driver says "left?" and the passenger says "right" so the driver goes right. :D

Comment: The problem is, writing a good question has not been demonstrated as necessary to get the solution to his "solve this once-and-done problem", and that's what he really wants.  All in all, not a good fit for SO.

Comment: The "follow up question" was meant to illustrate minute aspects of a language that may not be as obvious to noobs as you'd think (i.e., calling parameters "dash thingies"). It's easy for someone learned in bash to understand what that is; but to someone who only knows python for instance, they are as foreign as anything else in the language--perhaps even more so. I mean, "how do i google that"? "What do you even call those things"?

Comment: But @jmort253, makes great points. +1

Comment: @NoobSaibot - Unfortunately, that's a tough place to be. Without really knowing the terminology, we either must crack the books or be prepared to temporarily put our shields up to go into battle. Even as an experienced programmer, there are times I've had to ask questions without knowing all the terminology or where to even look, and it's always been a very humbling experience at the very least. The best we can do is try to learn as much as we can beforehand so we at least look like we're trying to meet those folks halfway.

Comment: Sometimes even just acknowledging our ignorance and lack of knowledge on where to look will disarm the "kick the dog" people enough to where they'll put their pitchforks away, at least long enough to be somewhat patient with us. :) For instance, saying you're new to bash and don't understand what the "dashes" do and couldn't find a good explanation might be better than declarations that we need answers right now this very moment. Hope this helps and good luck!

Answer (score 13):

After the edit of the question the question is much clearer now. The asker basically complains about the unwillingness of some answerers to give sufficient details in their answer (sufficient to understand if coming from a bit lower level). Well in that case the answer is just not useful to the asker and he/she should:

- not accept it (since it doesn't help the asker)
- once leave a single comment asking for more details
- if no more details are coming might downvote (although I wouldn't do that)
- go on (and try to learn somewhere else)

---

My advice is simple: Ignore everything that is not going towards the solution. And the solution is of course the solution for you, i.e. something you understand.

> **You**: How can I fly to the moon?
>
> **Smartguy**: Use a corollator.
>
> **You**: What is a corollator?
>
> **Smartguy**: What you don't know a corollator?
>
> **You**: Yes indeed I don't know, seems to be a non-trivial topic.
>
> **Smartguy**: Best is to read a book about it "Corollators in practice".
>
> **You**: Thank you for the suggestion. Can you also give me some more compact advice now?
>
> **Smartguy annoyed**: No I don't want to. Just read the book.
>
> **You always polite**: Okay thanks, I will.
>
> **Somebody else maybe**: By the way, using a corollator here just means pushing the start button.
>
> **You**: Thanks that helped me alot. +1

General guidelines:

- Always stay polite.
- Always act towards the goal of solving the question for yourself.
- All contributions from others are voluntary.
- Some answerers don't want to explain more than a certain amount. Their time is also valuable.
- Sometimes people get slightly impolite. Don't let that influence you, give a small comment and otherwise ignore it.
- If you don't get an answer that explains everything to you, just dig deeper somewhere else starting with the information that is already given. For example start reading that book.

I personally do not object explaining even the easier aspects if the questioner asks for it. But I won't do it repeated times. At some point everyone has to start learning for himself.

Comment: It's indeed a very important lesson to be learned on these here internets: the winner of a verbal confrontation is the one who walks away first. Ignore rudeness and non-constructive behavior, and for Pete's sake, don't _provoke_ someone who's already not helping you.

Comment: @JoshCaswell An additional trick I learned is to keep responses **short and focused**. That way you offer less attacking surface decreasing unpleasant responses and increasing the chance of helpful answers. If however a helpful answer comes, giving a big virtual hug (saying thanks) is never wasted.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Please see my edit. I believe my "probably-intended-to-be-goofy" replies has caused you to miss the point of my post entirely.

Comment: @NoobSaibot: Well, that reads like a much more reasonable conversation, but you still should have stopped after "I refuse to answer that question". You're right, though; I don't understand the point of your question. I don't see anything wrong with your hypothetical SO post. If somebody's not giving you the help you need and being a holier-than-thou prick, _just ignore them_.

Comment: @NoobSaibot After your edit, I also edited the answer. You basically made the mistake of continueing a conversation too long. After "I refuse to answer that question" what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @NoobSaibot: Also, your edit indicates that you think your word choices or means of expressing your reaction are incidental to the results of the conversation, but nothing could be further from the truth. Flippancy will indeed beget high-handedness; the more sober response that Trilarion recommends has a better chance of convincing the other person (even if she's acting like a bit of a jerk) that you're a reasonable human who will actually attempt to understand what she is saying.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I disagree. I think you're just a robot.

Comment: @Trilarion: That's still not *exactly* what's happening. **The Masters** were sincerely trying to help (in the beginning)--only they were trying to "teach the asker how to fish", when the asker really only needs one fish in this case. In my experience, it's as if many treat giving direct answers in this case as some sort of sin.

Comment: @NoobSaibot Yeah, but the whole point is that you cannot force anyone to give you more or other information than what this person wants to give you (unless you would pay for it). So every discussion will become useless at some point. Every answerer will give you advice as he/she sees fit and you take the part of it that you see fit. The roles are clear, you have no rights about others, others have no rights about you. State what you want and if you're lucky you'll get it. But don't get clued to a single answerer.

Comment: You've given an example of the extremally bad, overly too-broad and no-effort question. It was intendet?

Comment: Sorry I don't want to retype your long name. So you may not get a notification. The question is not extremely bad and anyway only an example. I did not bother chosing a real question. Just the communication strategy is of interest here because that's the important in my eyes: Stay focused, ask for the matter, do not get distracted, treat each one polite but with a critical distance. That works for every question.

Answer (score 13):

No, it's not.

StackOverflow is a place for "building a repository of programming knowledge", which means that answers should be solutions with enough explanation to be able to apply that in similar circumstances.  These answers usually require a small amount of effort from the OP to actually use them in their exact situation.

If what you want are copy+paste ready commands with no ability to adapt them to other situations, you should hire a consultant.

Comment: Firstly, I also suggested using StackOverflow chat for these types of questions (why does everyone keep missing that?).

Comment: Secondly, good post; but I'm not sure those are mutually exclusive. Take the [real-life question](http://superuser.com/q/720700) this post was based on (I asked in SuperUser because I wasn't sure if `bash` was a programming language). The title says exactly what I need, and I even have a simple diagram to make things clearer; but what if I didn't add my half-assed attempt at `unzip`? It turns out the reason I couldn't google a function call is because it doesn't exist. Is it inconceivable that there exists *no one* who could benefit from this question--present or future?

Comment: @Noob: That's a reasonable question for SuperUser