# Why did they ban me from asking questions for asking a poor question when I copied a question exactly that was asked at least four other times?

Tags: support, scope, post-ban, question-quality

Why did Stack Overflow ban me from asking questions for asking a "poor" question when I copied exactly the same question that was asked at least four other times on Stack Overflow? If it was a so poor question that it can get someone banned, I would think the other identical questions would have been notated as "poor" or something.

This is to me utterly unfair and unreasonable. It, and other similar behavior, has made me not even want to frequent Stack Overflow. It's been over a month, I really don't get such a penalty. One would think I cussed someone's mother or something.

Comment: why would you copy and post a question that has already been asked? If it has been asked before it doesn't need to be asked again.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/3933332 The ban will stay as long as you don't do something against it and waiting does not change anything.

Comment: So, besides what we can see on your profile.... There has to be some deleted Qs somewhere in there. From what is visible the Q ban shouldn't apply.... So yeah, you have to have so e pretty bad deleted Qs :/ in any case... Waiting won't do anything.... Read the link by rizier

Comment: Not very clear what "copied same question" is about, but you may want to read what to do if you have the same question as existing one but unhappy with answer - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334797/old-question-same-technology-not-satisfied-by-the-answer-what-to-do

Comment: Also re-read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - your posts look like they could get some editing to make samples more self-contained.

Comment: I was posting a particular snippet of js, and explicitly referring to it in my query. there was NO chance that the exact same snippet was being used in another question. so what would have been the point in looking at them? Can you tell me where I'm wrong here? It seems pretty obvious to me.

Comment: You just assume I have some pretty bad deleted questions, but I don't. I may have been told before that a Q was poorly formed, but nothing was ever mentioned about possibly being banned for it. I'm just assumed to be wrong...?

Comment: That assumption is quite reasonable, you might not be aware but we get 5-10 of these enquiries a week and they always have negatively scored deleted questions. Even when they swear they don't, they do. You can't get banned on the strength of a single post, as far as I know, there needs to be some sort of pattern. So are saying that you asked a single badly received question once, ever, and you've been banned for it? Because if that's true then yes, you probably have a valid complaint. If not, the system is working as designed - it's just stricter and less verbose than you would like

Comment: I only think i might have been warned of an impending ban. i had no idea that negative marks lead to such a penalty. I had no idea why my questions were so egregious. No one bothered to say anything constructive, and if one of my posts can be found where someone DID explain the problem, be my guest. many here have been resourceful enough, perhaps yet another error can be found. I surely don't remember a word being said about the danger I was in or how I might actually improve my questions. oh well. choose my battles, I suppose. thanks to you for at least admitting I might be reasonable.

Comment: If you are in fact subject to [a question ban](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) then you would have gotten warnings: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/159251 If [you didn't get a warning like that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290588/), that's a bug, and you should report it as such.

Comment: *One would think I cussed someone's mother or something.*, you did worse.

Answer (score 35):

I don't know what you're talking about with the "copied question" thing. [Here's the last question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299414/trying-to-find-out-why-this-javascript-isnt-working-as-it-should):

[image]

That question is unique within Stack Overflow. I don't see any evidence that you copied it.

Ok, ok, there are a ton of questions *like* it, questions where the asker really wants to ask *"how do I learn to debug the code I've written, how do I learn to read errors and interpret them, how do I learn to make incremental changes so I know when a specific change breaks something...?"* but instead asks, "what is wrong with this code?" and [gets handed a fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) instead of being taught anything.

So yeah, the *style* is common. But that doesn't make it *good*.

You've asked a few other questions like this. Maybe read the comments on your last one and spend some time learning the tools that you have ready at your disposal. Not only will this help you avoid getting blocked, it'll help you become a better programmer.

Comment: when I posted that question, I saw 4 other examples of the question nearly identical. ERGO, it appeared to me that, since the question has been asked before by others, it must be ok.

You ban me without notice & expect me to learn what I did wrong after the fact, when it will do me no good. It makes no sense to ban a person without a single warning, to be honest.

I'm a member of many forums where ppl are banned for flaming, etc. Not for improper formatting. Even QUORA isn't that harsh. so i have no idea how to remedy this, cept plead stupidity and forgiveness and go elsewhere.

Comment: When you wrote your question, you saw something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6T46u.png - notice how all of the questions listed are either closed, downvoted, or *both*? That's what you should've expected, and indeed what you got.

Comment: No. I DIDN'T notice, because it was popping up in the AJAX feed. I didn't actually go see the post. It was in the AJAX feed.

so NO, I didn't notice before I asked the question.

And honestly, [Closed] doesn't tell anyone WHY it's closed. If I HAD of noticed, I wouldn't have thought twice about it. Threads get closed all the time in forums. For various reasons. So [Closed] means nothing to me, til JUST now.

Comment: Ugh. Ok - [let's see if we can avoid this in the future.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335166/dont-show-closed-downvoted-questions-in-the-questions-that-may-already-have-y)

Comment: Well, certainly it's avoided if I'm banned. I can't hardly ask a stupid question if I can't ask any question, right?

Comment: SEE? I get -11 just for asking a legitimate question. and this IS a legitimate question. I can show how just because a question is closed, for newbies, this doesn't warn anyone WHAT to avoid.

And I'm penalized for this. Damn. Broken window the guys said. I'm thinkin' he's right.

Comment: @glennnall I don't see how you can get -11 if SO question is already deleted... If you are talking about this META questions - META votes are mostly different and reflect whether people agree or disagree with proposal/request (also I seriously suspect post is getting downvotes for being unclear and containing a lot of non-constructive rants)

Comment: @glennnall [Required reading about meta voting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta)

Comment: @glennnall something tells me you've confused SO with a forum. It's not, it's very different. The confusion may also come from the fact that "closed" here basically means "bad question, needs fixing". We have *many* rules you're expected to know before posting (you were given a tour and a help page before posting). We have to, SO is so popular that if we didn't enforce quality rules we'd drown in the flood of bad questions people would be posting (it's already happenning), and the experts (the people providing the best answers which make SO attractive in the first place) would leave the site.

Comment: as I've stated, I feel that banning a person with no warning is extremely harsh, and is neither constructive in actually educating someone to SO's preferred methods. 

I use the word "forum" in its broad definition. A place where numbers of people discuss things. And, again, as I stated, if that's what Closed means, and only means, here, I was not aware of that.

It seems everyone is more interested in telling me how wrong I am instead of even one attempting to consider my side, that I was simply unaware and asked a poorly formed question innocently and ignorantly.

Comment: all this is, of course, quite moot if i'm banned. If I'm to stay banned, I'm not sure why everyone is so interested in educating me now when no one was, when I committed the offense, to prevent me from getting banned.

If I'm to stay banned, I'm not even sure why I'm still replying to these "directions."

Comment: and when I first posted the question, it was worded just like the others (but without the unique js snippet, of course, which was the whole point of the query). I think I edited the question just after I wrote it, but at one point it was verbatim.

In any case, it was using a unique js snippet, so the question was obviously sincere.

If I am banned, and have to  "earn" good graces, then I shall have to stay banned. I was innocently wrong, and there's no way around it. I was banned with NO warning. I won't beg to be reinstated. This was a harsh penalty, and there's simply no arguing that.

Comment: *** I think what has gone unrecognized here is that I am NOT a js coder, I don't know the correct terminologies and I admittedly have a problem explaining what I'm trying to ask partly because of this. I think this is important in this particular lack of communication on my part. I also think it should be considered in this particular violation. I don't think anyone is willing to see past the violation and the policies, though. which is its own "broken window," as someone else pointed out.

Comment: That's correct. We concentrate on the **content** - never on the person who posted it, or the circumstances surrounding its having been asked.

Comment: that circumstances aren't weighed even after the violator has tried to explain, validly, in my opinion, tells me enough. I can't beat a perfect system, so...

Comment: I do hear what you're saying, and I sympathise. Have a think about it from the other side for a sec though...thousands of new questions per day, dozens to hundreds of new users posting those questions, weighed against the mission of the site which is to provide a repository of community-trimmed, high quality information. We just don't have enough bodies on the ground to deal with the onslaught, so the automated tools kick in. Now imagine everyone who crosses the threshold has recourse to challenge the automated decision, publicly or otherwise - it's just not going to scale.

Comment: @glennnall: No, your explanation makes no difference in the voting and closing.  However, the system is not designed to expect perfection; you are allowed to edit your questions to make them better, and votes are unlocked after an edit so the users casting them can change them.  The system is designed to be lax by ignoring new user mistakes, but to give you a chance to correct them.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a comment by [glenn nall](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1377165/glenn-nall) to [other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335157/why-did-they-ban-me-from-asking-questions-for-asking-a-poor-question-when-i-copi#comment-398806) which I think explains a possible reason for the negative reception of the post:

> when I posted that question, I saw 4 other examples of the question nearly identical.

This comment shows that you don't understand, or disagree with, the goals of Stack Overflow - creating a collection of good answers on real questions. Posting the same/nearly identical question multiple times does not help to achieve that goal.

Also, a downvote means in part "does not show any research effort" - you explicitly  stated that "I didn't actually go see the post" - so instead of making an effort to research the problem, you ignored data already provided and posted your question anyway. Since an automated research tool already found potentially useful information, most real users can see that you did not research at all and hence voted your post down.

To prevent this from happening to your future posts (under the same or a new account) please make sure to actually research your problem and **provide clear evidence of your research in the post**. Additionally, Stack Overflow *is not* a forum - if your post does not provide value for future visitors, expect close votes/downvotes.

Comment: I don't disagree with its goals, just its methods, in this case.

Comment: and this statement is inherently untrue: " you explicitly stated that "I didn't actually go see the post" - so instead of making effort for research problem you ignored data already provided and posted question anyway."

I was posting a particular snippet of js, and explicitly referring to it in my query. there was NO chance that the exact same snippet was being used in another question. so what would have been the point in looking at them?

Can you tell me where I'm wrong here? It seems pretty obvious to me.

Comment: @glennnall: Do you think that only a question with the *exact same snippet* could possibly help you? Do you not think you can learn how to solve your specific problem by reading answers on very similar problems? That's what research is about. If you didn't even look at the other questions, you can't possibly have known whether or not they would have helped you.

Comment: yes, I thought that, because I'm not a js coder. but because I didn't look at those questions doesn't mean I hadn't researched this problem. There are other places to research js that Stack Overflow (in fact, nothing says i DIDN'T look elsewhere in SO - I may or may not have looked at them at some point, just not right when I posted that Q), and I had spent a LOT of time trying to find out what was wrong with that code (turns out nothing was wrong with it, and most likely someone smart would have told me that had they the chance to.)

Comment: @glennnall: [It's not ok to ask "I don't care about your language" questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269484/103167) either.

Comment: @glennnall: If you don't bother looking at similar questions *when they're presented to you immediately before asking your question* then that's inadequate research, IMO. You're being handed opportunities on a plate, and it's only common courtesy to check those before asking the question. When you ask a question, that's asking other people to put time and effort into helping you. If you can't be bothered to follow four links to check that you're not asking a duplicate question, why should anyone be bothered to spend time helping you? (The "ajax feed" bit made no sense to me, btw.)

Comment: @glennnall:  I'd also strongly recommend putting more time into the question, too. Read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ all the way through. It'll take a while, and it takes a while to put it into practice, too... when I ask a question, it rarely takes me less than half an hour to go from "I think I need to ask a question" to submitting the question - because I take care to show what I've tried, what the results are, etc.

Comment: by 'AJAX feed' I meant that these things that are popping up while one is typing and changing as one types can be very fleeting. I may have seen similar or identical questions, but not even noticed the [closed] status. this is in fact what happened, because what I remember were the questions. When someone above pointed out that they're marked closed, I went and looked, and lo, there was the [closed] label. So that's what I meant.

I think I said elsewhere that I DID research this topic, & only after that posted the question. What's the sense of going back to a link I think I've already seen?

Comment: well, I think I've achieved my ration of people telling me all the things I've done wrong (@BenVoigt - ?), and telling me what to go read and study to prevent from being banned after I've been banned.

I thank all of you for your interest in me not getting banned and me learning how to do better, but I've been banned, and nary a one here has provided an idea that a) it could get lifted, or b) how I might remedy the situation. Only documentation on what I did wrong.

Thanks, ladies and fellas. at least one of you agreed that I had a point, but, alas, it's of no consequence. so I'm done.

Comment: @glennnall: Thought that being on the Meta FAQ was enough, but in case not: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Answer (score 12):

> I use the word "forum" in its broad definition. ***A place where numbers of people discuss things***.

And here is where you're confused, we don't discuss thing unless they are a) on Meta and thus are about the website and how it works or b) help clarify a question/answer.

Now first off, just by looking at your question [@Shog9 posted a screenshot of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335164/1028804) (man I want to be able to see deleted question/answers) within seconds I got the feeling you didn't even debug this code. Looking at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tLaLbzd/1/) I duplicate your alert inside your function, notice how it doesn't work. If you opened up your browser's developer console (normally <kbd>F12</kbd>) and reload the page we get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

Remove that star and press the run button and....It works.

Now I think I can understand the downvotes to your question and infact I would have downvoted too. Why? Well the downvote button lists common reasons why to downvote

> This question ***does not show any research effort***; it is unclear or not useful

The emphasized reason is why I would have downvoted. It appears to be that there was no basic debugging which could have caught this and this counts as *"research effort"*. Now I can't say if the other 2 lines would have worked but you could have improved your question by posting the relevant HTML because, in my view, as it stands even if you removed that `*` from your code how do I know that you have elements with those IDs if you didn't even do basic debugging to catch that star

> And, again, as I stated, if that's what Closed means, and only means, here, I was not aware of that.

When a question is closed the reason is posted below. Given, some of the reasons are generic like the *"unclear what your asking"* one but generally this can be worked out by reading some of the comments, people don't post a comment saying *"show us your code"* for no reason. If you still don't understand then post on Meta asking how to improve it

Finally

> When you wrote your question, you saw something like this: [i.stack.imgur.com/6T46u.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T46u.png) - notice how all of the questions listed are either closed, downvoted, or both? That's what you should've expected, and indeed what you got.

.

> No. I DIDN'T notice, because it was popping up in the AJAX feed. I didn't actually go see the post. It was in the AJAX feed. so NO, I didn't notice before I asked the question.

You didn't notice because you was ignoring them because they were in the AJAX Feed? I don't accept this and by ignoring them you also run the risk of being downvoted for asking a plainly duplicate question, again because of a lack of research effort. These questions that appear can sometimes help you answer your own question before you even post it, has done so a couple of times for myself.

Now I can only assume your not using some obscure browser which won't do this but all those links have `target="_blank"`, they open a new tab or window so your input wouldn't be lost. You could have done so yourself if you was worried they wouldn't. As what was said you should have expected that your question would get downvoted.

Comment: "because you was ignoring them" - "these questions ...has done so a couple of times for myself" - "if you was worried" - This from someone telling me that they don't accept my explanation. Nice.

Comment: @glennnall not sure what meaning you was trying to archive with the cherry picking but what i don't accept is that you didn't notice them. you did notice them because you observed they in fact appeared in the what you call the AJAX feed which, to my knowledge (by double checking my own posts), only appears when you ask a question so you can't have then noticed them when you went to edit, only when you went to ask a question

Answer (score -24):

man, never mind. I'm just a guy trying to learn stuff, I don't have a lot to teach anyone else. If that's the kind of techs that this site is trying to attract, then I'm not one.

There are other smart people on the planet who are happy to share their knowledge. Sorry I didn't rise to your expectations.

*********** I assumed by answering my own question in the way that I did that this thread would be closed or people would stop commenting on how wrong I am. I thought I made it clear that I'm done (days ago) with this thread and SO. I have found helpful people. I'm not worried about this thread anymore. Further "comments" (and most of the previous ones) are unnecessary. Trust me. **********

Comment: That's fine and as do we all, but learning generally involves lengthy research and experimentation. SO questions come *after* the research and experimentation. Because there are very specific rules about what you can ask, you may be disappointed. The one thing not to do is take that personal - its just rules that we all have to follow. If that doesn't work for you right now, there are other sites to ask questions.

Comment: This is the point I thought I was making in my answer, thinking that by answering my own question the thread would be closed. I stated earlier that I'm done with fighting a number of people who wish to insist that I see the error of my ways and learn how to not do it again after I've been banned. You are, of course, dead right. There are other, very helpful sites. I certainly don't need to participate in a site where I'm worried about performance ratings every time I'm trying to learn something. Can I just close this thread? This is ridiculous.