# Can a "noindex" be added to questions that are closed without answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Search engines don't care about the quality of a question; they will index the page if it is there. This is can be particularly annoying when you are searching Google, find a SO result, click through only to find the question as closed and there isn't a single answer provided.

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed
>   answers to every question about programming

If that is part of the mission statement, how does keeping a closed question *that doesn't have answers* around helping achieve that? I get that a question can be edited and re-opened, so deletion isn't a good option. Instead, could a noindex tag be added to the page to help search engines know the content isn't useful?

Yes, robots will still have to honor it. However, I feel like not providing the tag is only doing a disservice to ourselves.

**edit**

Of course, if the question is re-opened the tag can be removed and robots will pick it up next time.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239981/noindex-and-nofollow-for-bad-questions

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.  Kind of goes along with [this proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335166/dont-show-closed-downvoted-questions-in-the-questions-that-may-already-have-y)

Comment: I think you overestimate how useful this will be. Google does not update pages incredibly often once they've been indexed. They get indexed immediately upon being asked, and might remain that way for a couple weeks before getting reindexed. By that time, if it's still closed and unanswered, it will be auto-deleted by Roomba and Google will remove the result anyways. There are only [20,000 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+answers%3A0+score%3A1+locked%3A0) where this would be useful. Sounds like it's not really worth the time.

Comment: @animuson your query is only looking at questions with a positive score. Include negative scores (I did -10) and you get 80,000. I will give you it isn't much, but I wouldn't call that small.

Comment: @Joe But negatively scored closed questions with no answers get deleted automatically after 9 days. There's no point in doing anything special with them.

Comment: I don't like the idea. Questions should only be closed for a reason and the reason why a question got closed can be valid information (if it is not, that is only one wasted click and page load ...)

Comment: @chtz: No, questions get closed because of problems with the question, either it is on the wrong site (in which case having the wrong site appear in Google results just to say it's not the right place to look for that information is incredibly stupid) or the way the question was posed was terrible, which is not interesting to anyone but the asker who can learn how to ask better questions.  If the answer was "you cannot do that and here's why" the question will be answered, not closed.

Comment: Exception: duplicates; those lead to answers.

Comment: And if Google et al. are able to index all the duplicates, then they can boost the rank of the questions to which they link.

Comment: How about if we just quietly remove them using roomba?

Answer (score 44):

I think it's a good idea with one exception: duplicates.

Duplicates do have an answer, it's just one link further away. And the original question linked to may not appear in my Google search. After all, if we assume good faith, it did not appear in the duplicate asker's Google search either.

So **Yes, please**, but only **for non-duplicates**.

Comment: I can get behind that. It can even be taken 1 step more and do a redirect to the original

Comment: @Joe a redirect _does_ happen for low rep and non-logged in users. (or at least it _used to_ -- I have not tested it recently)

Comment: What about comments solving questions, and nothing happening after? No votes, no answers, nothing. There are some.