# Referrer search keyword statistics in edit reviews

Tags: feature-request

I've just seen an edit to a post that "corrects" the title to match the accepted answer. The edit was "correct" in a sense, but I felt it missed the purpose: the title was originally inaccurate because the author didn't know what keywords to search for.

I could argue that many of those who would be looking for the same information might use similarly vague search terms. However, that's hard to prove without data.

It would be nice if we could see the most frequent search terms leading to a question. That could give a (slightly biased) view of what people are actually searching for when they hit the question. If that could be combined with bounce rate, for example, it could help a lot so that reviewers can pick the best wording to help future searchers.

What do you think about this feature?

Comment: Keep in mind even if you *do* see lots of people using those incorrect search terms, that may well mean that people are searching for information about those actual terms, and are then disappointed about finding an answer that is entirely unrelated to those terms.

Comment: Quite beyond our control.  There is a goldmine of information that the machine could use to prevent stoopid questions from being asked.  But [it doesn't](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335166/17034).  It is not what they actually want to accomplish, they only want to put Yahoo Answers out of business.

Comment: @Servy That's why I'm suggesting to combine it with bounce rate. That should be helpful to find the terms that are actually relevant.

Comment: @HosamAly How do you expect to distinguish between someone who goes to the page, finds their answer, and leaves, vs. someone who finds the page, doesn't get an answer, and leaves?