# Why is my question flagged as "Questions with similar titles get downvoted...Be more accurate"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality-improvement

This is the title:

> Is it possible to track a single file in a Git worktree that is
>   untracked in the main tree. If so, how?

I am then warned that I should ask a more accurate question in the title because this sort of title gets stuff closed and downvoted, however this is exactly the question I'm asking.

I do not know the exact warning. When I clicked on it to copy and paste it disappeared. It appeared next to the title line in an orange box.

It doesn't get more accurate than that!

Should I ignore this warning? If not, what is wrong with that question?

Comment: You never should ignore any warnings given to you from the SE engine. These have to be taken seriously!

Comment: I don't fully understand the downvotes here. In general, when you receive such a hint, you should look at your question with scrutiny. If what you wrote here is **everything** that your question consists of, then it's probably really to unspecific. Can you link to the question (even if it's closed or deleted), or reproduce the text here?

Comment: @Marco13 I also don't understand the downvotes. I haven't asked the question yet, because I DO take warnings seriously.

Comment: And forgive my iritation. I'm seeing this rapidly downvoted with no indication as to what I'm doing wrong so I can fix it. This is a site for improvement, but this seems to be working very poorly.

Comment: When are you getting this warning?  Can you post a screenshot?  I am not seeing any warning after pasting that title into the input box of the "Ask a question" page.  Is it only whenever you click "Post your question"?

Comment: These warnings are triggered off simple regex expressions.  Far, far removed from anything resembling AI.  I suspect it is "Is it possible" that is the offending phrase.  "No" is a boring answer.  Consider leading with "How to".

Comment: I could be wrong, but the downvotes could be due to the less-than-welcoming language used in the question and subsequent comments. Note that if the new Code of Conduct were in place, that amount of snark could get the question and some comments flagged...

Comment: @HereticMonkey if the question can be improved in wording, please do so.

Comment: Downvotes indicate that the Meta SO users think that the answer to your question is "No". Meta downvotes do not affect your reputation.

Comment: @zero298 Uhm, yeah.... on the meta, open hostility is okay in order to attract the fights from the main site. But it is still a bad thing, and if you vote a good question down, you are doing bad things.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of asking

> Is it possible to ... If so, how?

Just ask how.

Your question might be fine, but the system is fooled by a *lot* of really poor questions that start out with "Is it possible...", so you get a warning. Just ask how to do the thing you're trying to do. Someone will tell you if it isn't possible.

Answer (score 10):

The system checks for [similar titles and their postscore and based on that it gives you that warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348825/578411)

The pattern that I think is suspicious is:

> Is it possible ..... If so, how?

The answer to questions like that are mostly *yes, [link to doc]*

Instead you could rephrase to

> How do I track a single file in a Git worktree that is untracked in the main tree?

and in the body of your question you explain what your git tree look like and which git magic commands you tried (and why you tried them) and what their result was.

Do know that based on your title alone I found [Per-worktree local exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48779515/per-worktree-local-exclusion) which might be related to your issue or maybe a common solution that didn't work for you. Make sure to include such references and how they failed in your context. It helps the answerers to focus on alternatives they know off.

The warnings you get are there to prevent avoidable mishaps. It is good to pay attention to them, as  you did, and try to find out what you can improve. There is a chance these warnings are false positives but you better be safe then sorry.

Answer (score -1):

> Should I ignore this warning?

You definitely shouldn't ignore any warning given to you by either the Stack Exchange Engine or more experienced site users.

Rather check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) 1st, what probably could be wrong with your question, and why it won't be well received ignoring the advise given there.

Most prominent places to check:

- [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [**What types of questions should I avoid asking?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: This is not really helpful. How should the title be re-worded then? That is a system generated warning they get.